# Why is replace() method not working properly but string splicing works

Tags: python, string, replace, str-replace

Recently I encountered a faulted output which I cannot understand.

I was solving a problem in which if the previous character in a string precedes the current character alphabetically then I have to uppercase the current character. On the other hand if the current character precedes the previous one alphabetically then the current character is lowercased. If both are same then no need to do any action.

**Eg:**

```
Input : ab cB GG
Output : aB cb GG
```

This was my code:

```
def transformSentence(sentence):
    for i in range(len(sentence)):
        s = sentence[i]
        p = sentence[i-1]
        if i ==0 or s == ' ' or p == ' ':
            continue
        if s == p:
            continue
        elif ord(s.lower()) > ord(p.lower()):
            sentence = sentence.replace(sentence[i], sentence[i].upper())

        elif ord(s.lower()) < ord(p.lower()):
            sentence = sentence.replace(sentence[i], sentence[i].lower())
    return sentence

print(transformSentence('ab cB GG'))
```

The output I got for this code block was:

```
ab cb GG
```

If you notice the output above, the **replace()** in the second `elif` block works! (Uppercase b changed to lowercase because it precedes c aplhabetically)

When I use `string slicing` and `concatenation` instead of `replace()` like below, it works perfectly on both blocks and gives me the expected output:

```
sentence = sentence[:i] + sentence[i].upper() + sentence[i+1:]
```

I need to know to know why **replace()** method does not work in the first `elif` block but works in the second one.

Comment: `replace` replaces **all** occurrences of a string, not just the one at the index you specify.

Comment: `replace(sentence[i],...)` means *replace* __every__ *occurrence of the string given by `sentence[i]`*.

Comment: Thank for you for clarifying @schwobaseggl and @ khelwood . Is there any way I can get the desired output using the replace method?

Comment: No, replace is not suitable for this operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace has updated the letter everywhere in sentence.

Comment: Thank you for clarification @Reena. Can you tell me how can I get the desired output using the replace method?